# How to display a chart with XML data in Windows phone 8 Mvvm

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I am making an app which hast to display currency rates by date from online XML.
I am using Sparrow Chart. When tested it with sample data, the chart displays data only when the GenerateDatas() method is called right in the ChartViewModel function but it is not displaying or refreshing when I call the function after asinc XML data read or with ICommand.

```
     List<CurrencyOfDate> list = new List<CurrencyOfDate>();
            foreach (XElement c in xmlData.Elements(ns + "Cube").Elements(ns + "Cube"))
                list.Add(new CurrencyOfDate()
                {
                    Date = c.Attribute("time").Value,
                    CurrencyTypes = (from k in xmlData.Elements(ns + "Cube").Elements(ns + "Cube").Elements(ns + "Cube")
                                     select new CurrencyType()
                                     {
                                         Name = k.Attribute("currency").Value,
                                         Value = k.Attribute("rate").Value
                                     }).ToList()
                });
            FeatList = list;
            if (FeatList != null)
            {
                foreach (var date in FeatList)
                {
                    var x = DateTime.Parse(date.Date);
                    PickedDate.Add(x);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < FeatList.Count; i++)
                {
                    CurList = FeatList[i].CurrencyTypes.ToList();
                }
            }
            MakeChartData();
}
private void MakeChartData()
    {
        try
        {
            IsDataLoading = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < CurList.Count; i++)
            {
                var selectedCurrencyRates =
                    (from c in CurList where c.Name == "GBP" select c).ToList();
                foreach (var selRate in selectedCurrencyRates)
                {
                    double parsedFromValue = Double.Parse(selRate.Value);
                        CalculatedRate.Add(parsedFromValue);
                }
            }
            GenerateDatas();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IsDataLoading = false;
        }
        Refresh();
    }

    private void GenerateDatas()
    {
        Refresh();
        try
        {
            IsDataLoading = true;


            this.Collection.Add(new Model(PickedDate[0], CalculatedRate[0]));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(PickedDate[10], CalculatedRate[10]));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(PickedDate[20], CalculatedRate[20]));
            this.Collection.Add(new Model(PickedDate[30], CalculatedRate[30]));


            IsDataLoading = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IsDataLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

And xaml:

```
     <chart:SparrowChart x:Name="Chart1" Height="409" Margin="0,0,22,0">
            <chart:SparrowChart.Legend>
                <chart:Legend Header="EUR/GBP" Height="55" Margin="155,0,172,4" Width="107" />
            </chart:SparrowChart.Legend>
            <chart:SparrowChart.DataContext>
                <viewModels:ChartViewModel/>
            </chart:SparrowChart.DataContext>
            <chart:SparrowChart.XAxis>
                <chart:LinearXAxis/>
            </chart:SparrowChart.XAxis>
            <chart:SparrowChart.YAxis>
                <chart:LinearYAxis/>
            </chart:SparrowChart.YAxis>
            <chart:LineSeries PointsSource="{Binding Collection}" XPath="X" YPath="Y" IsRefresh="True"/>
        </chart:SparrowChart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. This code works. The problem was that Collection was List type but it should be ObservableCollection.